# Tag Manager Variable Button Text based on Content

Tags: css-selectors, google-tag-manager

On every page (each page is a course) there are 3-4 buttons with:

`<a href="..."><div class="btn btn--small"> some text </div></a>`

and one

`<a href="...n-credits/"><div class="btn btn--small"> n credits</div></a>`

I want to create a variable of "n credits".

I tried the following: dom element, css selector `a[href*="credits"]` but the variable returns null.

Comment: Why not just making some CJS variable that would return the inner text of the clicked element?

Comment: I'm not certain how to do it as CJS and it is not on click but as a parameter for page_view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a CJS variable and in it:

```js
function(){
  return document.querySelector("a[href*='credits']>div.btn--small").innerText;
}
```

That returns the inner text of the first div that has the `btn--small` class and lives in an a that has `credits` in it.

Comment: I don't need the first. I need the one with "credits" in href. It could be the fourth or the fifth and "n" could be different but credits should always be in the href attribut of the a-tag.

Comment: Updated the selector. But this is pretty ugly now. I would suggest making front-end pushing a dataLayer event on these clicks. It's not a good practice to scrape DOM from GTM.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a wordpress site with no real development.